# Terminal Commands: For loop with echo

Tags: macos, terminal, command

I've never used commands in terminal like this before but I know its possible. How would I for instance write:

```
for (int i = 0; i <=1000; i++) {
    echo "http://example.com/%i.jpg",i
}
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The default shell on OS X is bash. You could write this:

```
for i in {1..100}; do echo http://www.example.com/${i}.jpg; done
```

Here is a link to the [reference manual of bash concerning loop constructs](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs).

Answer (score 31):

```
for ((i=0; i<=1000; i++)); do
    echo "http://example.com/$i.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Works, but you need to add curly braces around your var in most cases:  "foo${i}bar"

Answer (score 6):

Is you are in bash shell:

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

**jot** would work too (in bash shell)

```
for i in `jot 1000 1`; do echo "http://example.com/$i.jpg"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use for loop to append or write data to a file. example:

```
for i in {1..10}; do echo "Hello Linux Terminal"; >> file.txt done
```

">>" is used to append.

">" is used to write.

Comment: I think it should be like this (at least for shell on OS X):
`for i in {1..10}; do echo "Hello Linux Terminal" >> file.txt; done` if you want to write each line to the file or like this: `for i in {1..10}; do echo "Hello Linux Terminal"; done >> file.txt` if you want to write the total output, all the echo's, in once to the file.

Answer (score 2):

By using **jot**:

```
jot -w "http://example.com/%d.jpg" 1000 1
```